# OpenLayers pop-up form when a feature is selected

Tags: openlayers, feature-selection

Just wondering if anyone knows of anything to similar to clicking a feature (point) on an OpenLayers Map and it triggering a small pop-up form for completion?

I've found this in regards to adding text labels, but I don't want my label to appear...
https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/web_development/9781785287756/3/ch03lvl1sec34/adding-text-labels-to-geometry-points

Realistically, I want an illusion for the user to have interactivity with a contact page map. They can draw a point on the map (this code is complete), but now I'd like to offer them the opportunity to click that point they've just drawn and add text in a pop-up - is this possible?

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_popup_form - essentially this type of form but after the point has been drawn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tooltip packages such as [Popovers from Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/popovers/) ([example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/overlay.html)), [Tippy](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/), or [Popper](https://popper.js.org/) (on which the previous ones are based) all allow HTML content to be displayed such a tooltip. So you could trigger the creation of a tooltip within your `on('click')` even listener, that persists until the form is submitted.